# I have a Dutch residency permit as I work there but am from the UK - does the 90 day rule still apply if I visit another schengen country?

Tags: schengen

Identifying Schengen visa, residency permit, Austria immigration and 90 day ruling

Comment: The body of the question isn't a complete sentence and does not appear to contain a question.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 4):

> I have a Dutch residency permit as I work there but am from the UK - does the 90 day rule still apply if I visit another schengen country?

Yes, but it's not enforced strictly because there's no system in place for tracking internal border crossings.